# class variable not in the debugger

Tags: java, class, hashmap, scope

I am trying to find out the first repeating word using hashmaps, but I am not able to understand why the "map" is not created. I debugged and see no map variable in the debugger.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class HashMapTest {

static HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


 Boolean findRepeat(String word){
    if(map.containsKey(word) && map.get(word) > 1){
        return true;
    }
    else map.put(word, map.containsKey(word) ?  map.get(word)+1:1);
    return false;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMapTest hash = new HashMapTest();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : hash.map.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());

    }


    String[] arr = "I am a disco dancer you are not a dancer".split(" ");

    for (String word : arr){

        if(hash.findRepeat(word)) System.out.println(word);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: **I debugged and see no map variable in the debugger.**, can you show how exactly you did this? which IDE ?

Comment: I used eclipse and noticed that there is no 'map' variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashmap can't contain duplicate keys(HashMap)

and in your case  `if(map.containsKey(word) && map.get(word) > 1)` will always return false
it should be `if(map.containsKey(word) && map.get(word) == 1)`

Comment: Yeah, that solved. So stupid of me. However my focus shifted to why the 'map' member is not showing in Eclipse IDE debugger. Can you help with that also?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the findRepeat. Repeat will be if you already have an entry for any given item so you need to replace this condition

```
if(map.containsKey(word) && map.get(word) > 1){
```

with

```
if(map.containsKey(word) && map.get(word) > 0){
```

you need to check if map has any word till now.

Hope this helps